# Integral of the difference of two lagged CDF.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I am trying to proof why this statement holds, but without success. I  have also checked in Internet, but I could not find any solution:
Let $F(t)$ be a CDF of a random variable $t$, such that $t>0$:
Then, for $\Delta T > 0:$
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}[F(t+\Delta T) - F(t)]dt = \Delta T - \int_{0}^{\Delta T}F(t)dt$$
This expression is found in a journal:"Time-Dependent Renewal-Model Probabilities
When Date of Last Earthquake is Unknown" by Field and Jordan, and they argue that this is true due to the increasing monotonicity of $F(t)$ and its asymptote of 1.
However I still do not reconcile these arguments with the veracity of the expression.
Thanks for helping in advance.
Luis

Comment: $=\int_0^\infty (1-F(t))\,dt-\int_{\Delta T}^\infty (1-F(t))\,dt=\int_0^{\Delta T}(1-F(t))\,dt$. Or, in case integrals on the left don't exist by themself: what we need to show is true for $\Delta =0$ and derivatives of both sides with respect to $\Delta T$ are equal to $1-F(\Delta T)$.